# Why the Hong Kong Autonomy Act, when the US already enacted the HK Human Rights and Democracy Act?

Tags: united-states, hong-kong

On Nov 27 2019, Pres. Trump signed into law the [Hong Kong Human Rights and Democracy Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Human_Rights_and_Democracy_Act). On 25 June 2020, [US Senate passes Hong Kong Autonomy Act](https://www.hongkongwatch.org/all-posts/2020/6/25/breaking-us-senate-passes-hong-kong-autonomy-act).

> The [Hong Kong Autonomy Act,](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/senate-bill/3798/text) introduced by United States Senators Chris Van Hollen (D-Md.) and Pat Toomey (R-Pa.), defends Hong Kong against Beijing’s National Security Law by imposing mandatory sanctions on entities that violate China's obligations to Hong Kong under the *Joint Declaration* and the *Basic Law*, including police units cracking down on Hong Kong protestors or Chinese Communist Party officials responsible for imposing the National Security Law on Hong Kong.

1. What does this newer Act (HK Autonomy Act) do that the older (HK Human Rights and Democracy Act)  didn't?
2. Why didn't the US Senate just amend the older Act to include what's in the new Act? Do they need 2 separate Acts?

Comment: Passing laws of this kind has not just practical consequences, it is also politicial signalling. Hence you get the if-you-vote-against-this-you-are-unpatriotic-act instead of the act-to-amend-section-whatever-of-US-code-whatever.